# Set a Timeout to a Thread Class

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Hy!!

I have a thread class and want to set a timeout inside after 10 sec.

How is this been made?

Class:

```
public class HttpConnection extends Thread{

    List<NameValuePair> list;
    String url;
    Handler handler;

public HttpConnection(List<NameValuePair> params, String url, Handler handler) {

    this.list = params;
    this.url = url;
    this.handler = handler;
 }
@Override
public void run() {
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        String result;
        BufferedReader in = null;


                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(this.list));



            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            if(response != null){
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";
                String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + NL);
                }
                in.close();
                Message msg = Message.obtain();

                if ((result = sb.toString()) != null)
                {

                    msg.obj = result;   

                }
                else
                {
                    msg.obj = null;
                    throw new Exception("ERROR");
                }
                handler.sendMessage(msg); 
            }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Log.e("XXX", e.getMessage());
    }

    super.run();
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you should be able to use the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)'s awaitTermination method to set a timeout. Whichever class is creating and executing this thread should be able to call awaitTermination on the executor for 10 seconds. Is this what you are trying to do (set a timeout **ON** or **WITHIN** your thread)?

```
threadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: i want to make the timout in the class httpconnection

Comment: see my answer for setting the httpconnection timeout

Answer (score 3):

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 10000);//10 seconds
```

the httpconnection will timeout in 10 seconds, probably throwing some exception, in which case you can end your thread

Answer (score 0):

i may not sure we can use thread handler for these kind of tasks,you better use Asynchronous task for this purpose because it depends up on internet strength availability,it may takes more time to get response from server, so go through developer.android.com for this topic.

Answer (score -1):

```
super.run();
```

to

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
```

Hope it's help.

Comment: this will not act as a timeout and will not do what you want

Comment: Maybe this help: HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);